# How to restrict merge from specific branches

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

I would like only specific branches merge to specific branches.

Some example: I want to do `master` branch accept pull requests only from `test` branch, and `test` branch accept only from `development` branch.

How can I do this restriction on TFS/Git?

We have some policies about reviewers and build validation.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can restrict to a specific branch but using protected branches and configuring them may work.

Comment: Usage of protected branches cannot specify the pull request source branch or i don't know how to do. Thanks.

Comment: You've tagged it as azure-devops. Is your repo in there? In Azure Repos that is?

Comment: No azure-devops tags is selected by my mistake , sorry. its on premise tfs server.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you have branch policies you can do a workaround to achieve the goal:

In the build definition (that you specified in the build validation) add a PowerShell task that check the source branch of the pull request. When the source branch is not what you want the build will fail.

For example, in the following script, if the source branch is not `test` the build will fail, so add it in the `master` branch build validation:

```
$sourceBranch = "$(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch)"

if($sourceBranch -ne "test")
{
    exit 1
}
```

Comment: +1 for solving my problem.  Mileage may vary, but I found that the actual value of $(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch) was "refs/heads/test" and that the if statement needed to be $sourceBranch -ne "refs/heads/test".

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem via 3rd party web hook integration.

I developed nodejs expressapp and host it different server and i created integration rule which triggered when the pull request created. And i check source and target branches in my node app.

After that i added this integration to merge policies.

So cool , so easy. Thanks to everyone.